# Quartz scheduler Expression - 7 characters

Tags: cron, expression, quartz-scheduler

I am new to quartz scheduler, and I want to schedule a job for every sunday 8 AM. The cronmaker generated it as below.

```
0 0 8 ? * SUN *
```

My job ran successfully using this expression but I don't really understand this. It has 7 characters. I also googled but could not find much help. Can some one explain my expression.

Comment: quartz-scheduler is not the same thing as cron. The standard [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) format has exactly 5 time fields: minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week -- and it doesn't accept `?` for any of them. I suggest you update your question to make that clearer and avoid confusing future readers.

Comment: @Keith, Thanks for the clarification. I have updated the question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I just found at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

The below are the seven items in items in the expression.
-Seconds
-Minutes
-Hours
-Day-of-Month
-Month
-Day-of-Week
-Year (optional field)